# MicrosoftAjax date.format function not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome, string.format, microsoft-ajax

There is a bug in MicrosoftAjax.js String.format function when using Chrome 5.0.375. The function randomly returns 'undefined' for some dates.

I went around that by using jquery date formatter that comes with datepicker.

Comment: er... you should probably report the bug to Google or Microsoft.

Comment: Interesting, which dates fail?

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be best to file a bug either with MS.

You could also file a bug against Chrome at http://crbug.com/new